# Как реализовать задачу более кратким способом?

Tags: python, инспекция-кода

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from random import shuffle, randint

predict = [...] # тут список из 30 придуманных 
# предсказаний плюс 6 "ничего не изменится..."
# из условия задачи
shuffle(predict)
while input('Хотите узнать, что Вас ждет в наступающем году - Да / Нет :') == 'Да' :
    print(predict[randint(1,36)])
```

Можно ли как-то заменить `shuffle` и `while` на что-то другое, чтобы задача решалась еще короче?

Comment: shuffle(predict) ничего не дает, если вы берете по случайному индексу. можно выкинуть

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как у Вас неизменяема последовательность, стоит использовать кортеж.
Кортеж заполните своими данными и указать номер прямо в строке:

```
import random

predict = ('1. a', '2. b', '3. c')

while input('Хотите узнать, что Вас ждет в наступающем году - Да / Нет :') == 'Да':
    print(random.choice(predict))
```

**[UPDATE]**

Если номер нельзя хранить в строке, то запись выйдет длиннее, но не нужно будет заботиться о номерах:

```
import random

predict = {idx: i for idx, i in enumerate(('a', 'b', 'c'), 1)}
keys = tuple(predict.keys())

while input('Хотите узнать, что Вас ждет в наступающем году - Да / Нет :') == 'Да':
    key = random.choice(keys)
    print(f'{key}. {predict[key]}')
```

Comment: а как если я хочу еще помимо записки сделать вывод номера этой записки в списке, то как это вывести тоже?

Comment: то есть выводит записку с текстом и далее номер этой записки в `predict`

Comment: @Андр Обновил ответ. Строку можете форматировать как Вам необходимо.